# Managed C++ Assembly Attributes

Tags: .net, attributes, managed-c++

Is there a way to add assembly attributes to a Managed C++ assembly? In a typical C# project, there is usually a line of code in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file like the following one:

`[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Some Assembly")]`

I have a private assembly attribute that I want to add (not one of the version attributes that could be added through a resource file), and I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible - the easy way is to add an AssemblyInfo.cpp file and put:

```
#include attributes.h //your attribute decl
[assembly: MyCustomAttribute()];
```

It can be in any file you want, though.

*edit* - added required semicolon for assembly attribute

Comment: One very minor thing, this worked, but a semicolon must be added to the end of the statement.