# Creating a strongly-named managed (/clr) C++ assembly

Tags: .net, c++, clr, sign

I have a managed C++ assembly using the `/clr` switch that I am trying to sign as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656412/is-there-an-easy-way-to-sign-a-c-cli-assembly-in-vs-2010) with the following post-build step:

```
sn -Ra "$(TargetPath)" MyKey.snk
```

However this is giving the following error:

```
C:\Path\Assembly.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you marked the assembly for delay signing in AssemblyInfo.cpp?

```
[assembly:AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("MyKey.snk")];
[assembly:AssemblyDelaySignAttribute(true)];
```

Comment: Where does this go in a Managed C++ assembly?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158821/managed-c-assembly-attributes)

Comment: So damn annoying that this was/is not documented.  Spent over two days trying to figure out why this wouldn't work when switching to 32-bit configuration but was not required w/ 64bit.

Answer (score 7):

I figured this one out in the end - as per the linked question I cannot just set the `Linker/Advanced/KeyFile` option and expect it to work - I need to use `sn.exe` to sign the assembly, however I **also** still need the `Linker/Advanced/KeyFile` option to be set.

In short to sign a /clr assembly you need to both:

1. Specify a keyfile in the `Linker/Advanced/KeyFile` properties page
2. Use `sn.exe` to sign the assembly as a post-build step

(I believe that using the `[assembly:AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("MyKey.snk")]` is equivalent to setting the keyfile in the project properties dialog).

Comment: It should work, however sometimes It doesn't and you have to use attributes.

Answer (score 6):

The [marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117596/73025) helped to reach the final solution (so it receives a +1 from me).

However had to spent several frustrating minutes figuring out how to create an `AssemblyInfo.cpp` in VS2010.

Below is the "more" complete answer to the problem.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;
using namespace System::Runtime::CompilerServices;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace System::Security::Permissions;

[assembly:AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("YourAssembly.snk")];
[assembly:AssemblyDelaySignAttribute(true)];
```

Then as a post-build step, run `sn -Ra YourAssembly.dll YourAssembly.snk`

Comment: I needed semi-colons after the [assembly] attributes.